# How to get the content between different xml tags

Tags: xml, tags

Here is a fragment of my xml document:

```
<Title>example<\title>
This article is an example
<section>intro<\section>
<p> bla blablablablablablablablabla.
Here is an image <image>blablablabla<\image> <caption>example image<\image>
</p>
.
.
.
.
```

The tags are nested so first I need to get the structure of the doc and then the content. How to scan the doc and get the whole structure?

It is easy to get "exmaple" between <\title>. How to only get the content "This article is an example", which is not enclosed by any tags.

Comment: This is not valid XML. Are you trying to parse XHTML manually instead?

Comment: What language and libraries are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the xml file you are showing here for example is not a valid xml file. It does not follow xml conventions. You can learn about xml files from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp)

Secondly, tt depends which language you are using for your app and how you want to access it.

Example, you can access its memebers from JavaScript using DOM. A very simple way. You can get help about it from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dom.asp).